# Flags Behind Countries name are not showing up

Tags: php, html, sql, image, tags

So yeah, I have in DB Country code and Country name I select both and I try to put the flag behind the country name

SQL

```
 $sql = "SELECT country,country_code FROM DB";
```

the row in my table which it's supposed to be in the Flag and the country name

```
    echo "<td>" "<IMG SRC='http://api.hostip.info/flag.php' width='30' height='20' BORDER='0' ALT='. $row["$country_code"] .'/>"; " . $row["country"] . </td>";
```

only the country name shows up. Any solution, please ?

Comment: you need to sort out that concatenation in your string

Comment: the country_code seems to return just that (a code) not an icon, image or path to an image.  You'll need to match the code with a place where the actual images are found.  Also, please add a [mcve] to your question, it cannot be answered fully with what you have provided

Comment: Maybe because of flag.php doesn't return an image or is not an image

Answer (score 1):

First off, you'll need to properly concatenate strings with your actual variable. Second, combine that to the appropriate url that API needs.

It seems the API needs a two letter ISO country code:

```
http://api.hostip.info/images/flags/us.gif
```

Like so.

So in turn, just apply the concatenation basic principle along with adding the proper url:

I'd suggest do it this way though.

```
$country_code = strtolower($row['country_code']); // do this in application level or on DB level mysql function LOWER(country_code)
$country = $row['country'];
echo "
<td>
    <img src=\"http://api.hostip.info/images/flags/{$country_code}.gif\" width=\"30\" height=\"30\" alt=\"{$country_code}\" />
    {$country}
</td>
";
```

Sidenote: In addition to that code, you could also add a validation that checks whether that country code image exists, so that you could also add a "no image" fallback in the event that the image does not exist on the API.

[Correct PHP way to check if external image exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13956939/correct-php-way-to-check-if-external-image-exists)

Answer (score 1):

Just update your echo to:

```
echo '<td><IMG SRC="http://api.hostip.info/images/flags/'. $country_code .'.gif" width="30" height="20" BORDER="0" />' . $row["country"] . "</td>";
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work it directs me to this link http://api.hostip.info/images/flags/